# Change Git zip folder name?

Tags: git, github, repository

I have customers downloading my repository but the folder name is giving problem.
The folder name needs to a certain word, in order to upload it to a ecommerce solution, Prestashop.
So right now the customers needs to download the file by [clicking the clone button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZUGq.png), unzip, rename the folder and zip it again.

Is there a way to rename the folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the repo directory name by adding the repository as a remote.

```
git remote add [name-of-folder] <git_url/ssh>
git fetch [name-of-folder]
git checkout [name-of-folder]/[branch]
```

Comment: Does that mean when clicking on the button "Download ZIP" on the web github, the folder name gets that exactly name?

Comment: The example provided will only rename that folder locally. On Github, the naming structure of the zip file generated by the "download" button is [repo-name]-[branch].